C++ WebAssembly module libsodium integration
I'm new to the world of WebAssembly.
I'm just starting to experiment with it.
I'm trying to write my own C++ module that uses some third-party libraries.
For example, I'm trying to implement a C++ WebAssembly module that utilizes the libsodium library.
So, I've added to my code:
#include <sodium.h>

Since I don't have libsodium in my local environment (I'm using Mac OS), I installed it using brew libsodium.
So, I've tried to compile my module with this command:
emcc -o example.html module.cpp -s WASM=1 -L/usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib -lsodium -I/usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/include
But I keep getting warnings and errors:
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-aead_aegis128l.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-aegis128l_soft.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-aead_aegis256.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-aegis256_soft.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-aead_aes256gcm.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-aead_chacha20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-aead_xchacha20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_auth.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-auth_hmacsha256.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-auth_hmacsha512.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-auth_hmacsha512256.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_box.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_box_easy.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_box_seal.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-ed25519_ref10.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-core_hchacha20.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-core_hsalsa20_ref2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-core_hsalsa20.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-core_salsa_ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-softaes.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_generichash.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-generichash_blake2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-blake2b-compress-ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-blake2b-ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-generichash_blake2b.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_hash.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-hash_sha256.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-hash_sha512.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-hash_sha512_cp.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-kdf_blake2b.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_kdf.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-kdf_hkdf_sha256.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-kdf_hkdf_sha512.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_kx.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_onetimeauth.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-onetimeauth_poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-poly1305_donna.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-argon2-core.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-argon2-encoding.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-argon2-fill-block-ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-argon2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-blake2b-long.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-pwhash_argon2i.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-pwhash_argon2id.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_pwhash.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_scalarmult.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-x25519_ref10.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-scalarmult_curve25519.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_secretbox.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_secretbox_easy.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-secretstream_xchacha20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_shorthash.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-shorthash_siphash24.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-shorthash_siphash24_ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_sign.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-sign_ed25519.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-keypair.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-open.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-sign.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_chacha20.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-chacha20_ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_stream.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_salsa20.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_xsalsa20.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-verify.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-randombytes.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-codecs.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-core.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-runtime.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-utils.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-version.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-salsa20_xmm6-asm.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-salsa20_xmm6.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-curve25519_sandy2x.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-fe51_invert.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-fe_frombytes_sandy2x.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-sandy2x.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-box_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-box_seal_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-core_ed25519.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-core_ristretto255.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-crypto_scrypt-common.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-scrypt_platform.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-pbkdf2-sha256.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_nosse.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-scalarmult_ed25519_ref10.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-scalarmult_ristretto255_ref10.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-secretbox_xchacha20poly1305.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-shorthash_siphashx24.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-shorthash_siphashx24_ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-obsolete.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_salsa2012_ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_salsa2012.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_salsa208_ref.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_salsa208.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-stream_xchacha20.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsodium_la-randombytes_sysrandom.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libaesni_la-aead_aes256gcm_aesni.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libaesni_la-aegis128l_aesni.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libaesni_la-aegis256_aesni.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libarmcrypto_la-aead_aes256gcm_armcrypto.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libarmcrypto_la-aegis128l_armcrypto.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libarmcrypto_la-aegis256_armcrypto.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsse2_la-poly1305_sse2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsse2_la-pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_sse.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libssse3_la-argon2-fill-block-ssse3.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libssse3_la-blake2b-compress-ssse3.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libssse3_la-chacha20_dolbeau-ssse3.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libsse41_la-blake2b-compress-sse41.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libavx2_la-argon2-fill-block-avx2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libavx2_la-blake2b-compress-avx2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libavx2_la-chacha20_dolbeau-avx2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libavx2_la-salsa20_xmm6int-avx2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'libavx512f_la-argon2-fill-block-avx512f.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.19/lib/libsodium.a: archive member 'librdrand_la-randombytes_internal_random.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode

wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _embind_register_class
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _embind_register_class_class_function
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _embind_register_class_class_function
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _embind_register_bindings
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_get_global
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_get_property
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_decref
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_as
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_run_destructors
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: sodium_init
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: randombytes_buf
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: crypto_aead_aes256gcm_encrypt
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: sodium_init
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/bn/gbn9_dvx3vq3h4k_k2wm0k4w0000gp/T/emscripten_temp_qg8ss4u4/module_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_new_cstring 

I don't understand if I'm following the correct approach or if I'm misunderstanding something conceptually.
Is it necessary to compile external libraries for WebAssembly?
If so, how can I compile libsodium? From the documentation (https://doc.libsodium.org/), it seems to be compatible with WebAssembly.

The library installed by Homebrew only works on macOS and your CPU model.
WebAssembly has its own conventions, so everything has to be recompiled for it.
Download the libsodium source code:
git clone --branch=stable https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium

The run the build script for Emscripten:
cd libsodium
./dist-build/emscripten.sh --standard

After a while the libsodium-js directory contains includes files and a libsodium.a file compiled for WebAssembly.
